# Problems in linking PCL and OpenNI

Tags: visual-studio-2010, openni, point-cloud-library

I have installed **OpenNI 1.5.2.23** and **PCL 1.6.** I tried to run the **openni_grabber.cpp** example and I got the following error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x7534c41f in openni_grabber.exe: Microsoft C++ exception:    openni_wrapper::OpenNIException at memory location 0x0042f3fc..
```

and it indicates a green arrow on line:

```
pcl::Grabber* interface = new pcl::OpenNIGrabber();
```

What could be the problem?

my OpenNI Viewer is working from openni samples.

Comment: i get the following output in debug mode:

First-chance exception at 0x7534c41f (KernelBase.dll) in openni_grabber.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: openni_wrapper::OpenNIException at memory location 0x0036f07c..
Unhandled exception at 0x7534c41f (KernelBase.dll) in openni_grabber.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: openni_wrapper::OpenNIException at memory location 0x0036f07c..
First-chance exception at 0x0f7cabd1 (pcl_io_debug.dll) in openni_grabber.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.